# Citações no element blockquote

Tags: html

De que maneira um visitante irá saber a fonte da citação de um elemento *blockquote*?

```html
 <blockquote cite="http://www.worldwildlife.org/who/index.html">
For 50 years, WWF has been protecting the future of nature. The world's leading conservation organization, WWF works in 100 countries and is supported by 1.2 million members in the United States and close to 5 million globally. <p>Fonte do codigo acima: <cite>http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_blockquote.asp</cite></p>
</blockquote>
```

Comment: Não percebi a tua pergunta. O `cite` é onde o visitante pode saber a fonte da citação. O que te falta?

Comment: Mas como ele vai saber? Pelo menos no Firefox ao passar o mouse em cima da citação não aparece nada.

Comment: já experimentou usar um click do javascript que o leva para uma janelinha escondida ou role a página para o lugar? pois comentou que no firefox não aparece nada, mas no ie do Windows phone só se clicar

Comment: É @flourigh acho que atualmente isso varia de navegador pra navegador mesmo. O desenvolvedor da pagina que terá que fazer algum codigo para mostrar a citação, se ele quiser, tornando o atributo `cite` um pouco inutil pois não é compativel em todos os navegadores como você mesmo disse. Obrigado cara hehehe.

Comment: pois é, cada navegador trata de uma forma, mas, em javascript é bem simples de fazer e fica bonito. experimente $("cite").click(function() {}); este no caso precisa de jquery

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Qual é a diferença entre as tags \`<q>\` e \`<blockquote>\` e \`<cite>\` no HTML? E como usa-las corretamente?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/330063/qual-%c3%a9-a-diferen%c3%a7a-entre-as-tags-q-e-blockquote-e-cite-no-html-e-co)