# Qual é a diferença entre as tags <q>, <blockquote> e <cite> no HTML? E como as usar corretamente?

Tags: html, html5, semântica

Qual é a diferença entre `<q>` e `<blockquote>` e `<cite>`, pois tudo me parece ser para citação. Existe alguma boa prática ou forma correta de usar corretamente essas tags?

Podemos usar essas tags umas dentro das outras visto que no HTML também existe o atributo `cite=""` e as aspas simples `" "`.

Também reparei que cada uma dessas tags é renderizada de forma diferente na página. Me parece que o *`user-agent`* tem um estilo CSS particular para cada uma das tags, uma tem itálico (`<cite>`) outra não, uma tem uns espaçamentos (`<blockquote>`) outras não...

```html
<q>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</q><br>
<blockquote>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</blockquote><br>
<cite>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</cite><br>
```

Afinal como essas tags devem ser usadas? Existem um valor semântico diferente para cada uma delas, ou todas querem dizer a mesma coisa e não há diferença entre elas?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Tudo questão de semântica do HTML

O elemento HTML `<cite>` representa uma referência a um trabalho artístico. Deve incluir o título do trabalho ou uma URL de referência, que pode ser em uma forma abreviada de acordo com as convenções usadas para a adição dos metadados de citação.

O Elemento HTML `<blockquote>` (ou Elemento HTML de citação de bloco) indica que o texto incluído é uma longa citação. Normalmente, este é processado visualmente pelo recuo (ver Notas sobre como mudá-lo). A URL para a fonte da citação pode ser dada usando o atributo cite, enquanto uma representação de texto da fonte pode ser dada usando o `<cite>` elemento.

O elemento HTML `<q>` indica que o texto em anexo é uma cotação curta em linha. A maioria dos navegadores modernos implementam isso cercando o texto entre aspas. Este elemento é destinado a citações curtas que não exigem quebras de parágrafo; para citações longas, use o elemento `<blockquote>`.

Referências:

https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTML/Element/cite 
https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTML/Element/blockquote 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/q

Comment: Gustavo obrigado pela resposta, agora as coisas estão mais claras!

Answer (score 12):

Em tese cada um pode ser usado quase para o mesmo fim, mas não deveria, o uso correto é semântico e indica a intenção do que está fazendo. Note que a apresentação pode ser personalizada até para serem iguais (ou quase), ainda que faça pouco sentido.

`<q>...</q>` você faz um citação *inline*, ou seja, no meio de um texto. Minha experiência é que serve mais para um destaque, ainda que deveria ser só usado como uma citação real de alguma coisa dita anteriormente. É como usamos o ``` `` ``` aqui no site através do *markdown* (mas ele tem a semântica de citação de código que aqui é diferente da citação básica).

`<blockquote>...</blockquote>` é o mesmo, porém ele cria parágrafo (em certa medida funciona como um `<div>` com função mais específica), por isso ele não é exatamente igual ao `<q>`. Ele deve ser usado para um destaque isolado da citação e possivelmente, mas não necessariamente, decorado com CSS de forma diferente. É como usamos aqui o `>` no *markdown* (existe a citação de código também, que é um pouco diferente, mas no fundo cai no mesmo internamente, no HTML).

`<cite>...</cite>` é para definir uma referência e não para colocar a citação, o texto em si, embora possa usar também. Principalmente para indicar quem disse, é mais para colocar um URL com o texto do autor ou material citado, ou seja, indica a fonte. Pode facilitar a formatação e buscas de ferramentas diversas. Pode ser usado dentro do `<blockquote>`.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Conceptual.md).

Comment: pois é, eu já vi o `cite` como atributo de um `<blockquote>`, informando a url da origem... mas acho que não um browser faz algo com isso.

Comment: Sim, é só pra dar semântica mesmo, não tem uma função clara. Então você pode usar como quiser. O Google deve entender de forma especial, seu app pode fazer o mesmo.

Comment: @Maniero muito obrigado pela resposta, bem esclarecedora. Apenas aceitei a outra resposta pois ela veio alguns minutos antes :)

Answer (score 5):

`<blockquote>`: É uma citação longa ou uma citação que você precisa isolar dos demais conteúdos a sua volta, sendo que navegadores costumam indentar seu conteúdo usando `margin`. O atributo `cite` recebe uma URL que diz de onde aquela informação veio (de uma notícia, mensagem, comentário...).
Caso você queira fazer uma menção e também citar visualmente de onde aquela citação veio faça o seguinte:

```
<figure>
    <blockquote>
    Essa é uma citação a nível de bloco.
    </blockquote>

    <figcaption>
        <span class="author">João Pedro</span>
        <cite>Qualquer trabalho criativo</span>
        <data>05/10/2020</data>
    </figcation>
</figure>
```

Essa é a forma mais semântica e ideial de fazer essa estrutura. Claro, você pode também colocar um `<footer>` dentro do `<blockquote>` para fazer essa atribuição, mas isso não é recomendado pela específicação do HTML.

`<q>`: Representa uma citação in-line, onde navegadores mais novos inplementam as aspas automaticamente, mas você pode fazer o seguinte pra confirmar que as aspas vão ser aplicadas:

```css
q::before {
    content: open-quote;
}

q::after {
    content: close-quote
}
```

```html
<q>Isso é uma citação</q>
```

Como essa é a maneira que browsers novos usam para auto-aplicar as aspas, não tem como duplicar as aspas tanto em browsers antigos como em novos.
Ele também pode receber o atributo `cite`.

`<cite>`: Serve apenas para citar trabalhos criativos, nada além disso. Se você quiser citar o autor/empresa que fez aquele trabalho/conteúdo, use uma tag `<b>` ou um `<span>` com uma `class="author"`, não use o `<cite>`. É esse carinha que normalmente recebe o itálico.

**PS**: Você pode muito bem alterar os estilos dos elementos acima e de qualquer outro para deixa-los da maneira que você quiser. Isso é normal, só tenha cuidado para você não deixar o elemento em um formato confuso.